# Rails: How to join models with data from an aggregate table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am attempting to join an aggregate table with the object types it represents.

Here's a simplified schema of the aggregate table:

#### Aggregate Table

```
aggregate_table[0] => {
  item_type: 'cars',
  item_id: 8,
  count: 12,
  time: 'Thu, 01 Nov 2012 00:00:00 PDT -07:00'
}

aggregate_table[1] => {
  item_type: 'people',
  item_id: 23,
  count: 48
  time: 'Thu, 01 Nov 2012 00:00:00 PDT -07:00'
}
```

Is it possible to return **Car** objects merged with their respective counts taken from the AggregateTable?

Here's a more descriptive real life use case:

1. Query the aggregate table where `item_type: people`, with a specific given data range and the results sorted by **count**.
2. Query the **People** model for **item_ids** returned by the aggregate table query.
3. Merge **People** objects with corresponding aggregate table results, for example: `People#count`

My attempts to accomplish this with a left outer join were fruitless. What is the correct way to do this?

---

Running PostgreSQL 9.1 and Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 2):

You should use [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

```
Class Aggregation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true
end
```

And include an `has_one` reverse association (not required but may be useful) in associated classes.

See the documentation above for the exact database schema.

Then for your questions:

**1** I am not sure what you call "specific given data" but you can query Aggregation this way:

```
Aggregation.where(:item_type => "People").order(:count)
```

**2** The following line will give you the resulting people(s) (you should rather use Person/people, Rails convention)

```
Aggregation.where(:item_type => "People").order(:count).map(&:item)
```

Or

```
People.joins(:aggregation).order("aggregations.count")
```

You should be able to use condition on `Aggregation` or `People` or both.

**3** I am not sure that you really need to "merge". The following line will give you `count` from `aggregations` table:

```
People.joins(:aggregation).order("aggregations.count").each do |p|
  puts p.aggregation.count
end
```

You should perhaps add an `includes(:aggregation)` to avoid a query per "people".

If you want to be able to write `p.count` rather than `p.aggregation.count` you could use `delegate` in `People` class:

```
class People
  delegate :count, :to => :aggregation
end
```